# how to preserve new-line in solr

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

am new to Solr. I hav successfully indexed the data from my database (using dataImporthandler) n retrieved data(using solr admin page).

The table which am indexing has a coloumn which has field type '*text*' .The problem am facing while indexing is am losing *new-line* character which is present in Database table(*new-line*).

Am indexing this field to paragraph_t(dynamic field).  So when am retrieving data(using solr admin console) the whole data in this field comes in one single paragraph(which I want with new-line character)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Solr does not modify the Stored data. The analysis only occurs on the indexed data. So you would have the data as is unless the new line is lost when the client handles it or stored in some other format. Check the Solr xml response.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jayendra. n Sory my mistake, actually I was getting the response in XML format(wt=xml) in which the required field ws in single para. but when I tried copying the text content in my editor it had all the necessary characters(new-line).

Comment: So the new lines are preserved. You can verify from the view source and it should be available when you read it through your clients.